# Migrating to Vim from RubyMine - Interpreted Auto completion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, vim-plugin

Up until last week, I had been using RubyMine for my Rails development. I know it has a vim plugin but I have been working on migrating my development to vim and tmux. I don't want to keep using the mouse and VIM gives me a lot more flexibility. I have found plugins and workarounds for almost all the features I care about except the "interpreted auto complete" functionality in my first screenshot below. RubyMine interprets the whole rails application and offers sorted-by-relevance suggestions (as you can see, it's showing me instance variables and methods for the class in question and the modules it includes) THEN it shows (less relevant) methods available on the `Object` class. It also shows the method signature when there's one.

Also, in my second screenshot, you can see how RubyMine offers autocompletion for core Ruby classes.

Compare this to the bottommost screenshot. I do have completion but there's no way to find what I'm looking for. I'm using `ctags` , `YouCompleteMe`, `vim-rails`, `vim-ruby` and I also tried installing `eclim` to see if it makes a difference.

Is there a plugin I've missed that can enhance my auto completion? It doesn't look like RubyMine is doing something super crazy. `pry` can give me the same 'power' if it were running in the same 'context'.

**First Screenshot (RubyMine interpreted auto complete):**

[image]

**Second Screenshot (RubyMine core Ruby classes auto complete):**

[image]

**Third Screenshot (vim omnifunc + ctags):**

[image]

Comment: Obligatory Vim is not an IDE comment. Also possible duplicate of [Better autocomplete in VIM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15723209/438329)

Comment: Vim does have the capability to be an IDE. My current setup is very powerful (especially with CtrlP, vim-rails, vim-fugitive, etc) and I've only switched to Vim less than a week ago. The OP there was asking for autocompletion, which I do have (I mentioned many solutions in my question but I'm not fully satisfied). I'm looking for interpreted autocompletion if there's any out there =)

Comment: Haha... I revisited his question and it looks like I am asking for the same thing but I'm still not satisfied with the proposed answers. His question was asked over a year ago and obviously the technologies in question have changed; how can we re-ask the same question without "duplicating the question"?

Comment: Hm, as you don't seem to be reluctant to install plugins, you could try [vim-monster](https://github.com/osyo-manga/vim-monster) and see if it makes a difference. This is a completion plugin for ruby, which uses [rcodetools](https://rubygems.org/gems/rcodetools) for a better completion.

Comment: I forked tpope's `vim-ruby` yesterday and modified it so I can see method signatures now :-).. I still need to allow it to insert the whole definition for me when I complete and make sure it integrates well with YouCompleteMe and I'll post to github =) Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: how did you end up doing with that Abdo? It's something I would be interested in.

Comment: @whossname I wrote my answer below :-)

Comment: haha yeh, I saw it right after commenting. Do you still use that setup?

Comment: @whossname I used it for a bit but then switched back to YouCompleteMe as it is faster than Supertab (this might have changed after Vim 8's release). So I would give it a shot again. Personally, I started using named parameters more (since order doesn't matter) but yup, I should give supertab another shot now that you reminded me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Important Note**
This solution only works for Ruby **1.9+**

I forked 'vim-ruby' at https://github.com/zxiest/vim-ruby and modified it as such:

- Method signatures now appear in completion.
- I disabled sorting by name for methods.

**Plugins and Settings**

**vim-rails**
I'm using vim-rails https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails

**supertab**
I'm using supertab https://github.com/ervandew/supertab instead of `YouCompleteMe` (mentioned in my question) although `YouCompleteMe` is super fast and automatic but there are currently some compatibility issues between my it and my `vim-ruby` fork.

**vim-easytags**
I'm using vim-easytags https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags

Add this to your `~/.vimrc`

```
:set tags=./tags;
:let g:easytags_dynamic_files = 1
```

Make sure to `touch ./tags` in your project directory.

Issue `:UpdateTags -R **/*.*` from vim in order for easytags to generate your tags file.

**Remap omnicomplete**

In order for `omnicomplete` to pop up, by default, we have to hit `<C-X><C-O>`. I remapped this to `<C-Space>` by inserting the following in my `~/.vimrc`:

`inoremap <C-@> <C-x><C-o>`

I now press `tab` when I want supertab to complete my code and `Ctrl+Space` when I want omnicomplete to trigger and show method signatures for me. There's definitely a better way to integrate this (i.e. getting supertab to call omnicomplete after a dot)

And here goes the screenshot! Notice that method sorting being off allowed my custom `resize` method to appear on top and the signatures now appear in the completion (as well as in the editor when enter is pressed!)

[image]